# rails 4-1 error: undefined method `map' for ThreadSafe::Cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I just updated to rails-4-1-stable and I'm experiencing the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for #<ThreadSafe::Cache:0x007fca66162668>
```

The error is caused by this line of code (in my User model), where I want to set all timezones for validation:

```
validates :time_zone, inclusion: { in: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.map{ |el| el.last.name }, allow_nil: true }
```

Why is that happening and what would be the best way to fix it?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

Gary Wright's comment on [sjobe's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950540/validates-inclusion-of-no-longer-working-the-same-in-rails-4-1#comment36837662_22950776) nails it, the implementation of `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map` has changed in Rails 4.1 to now return a `ThreadSafe::Cache` object, which doesn't respond to the `include?` method.

You can fix it with:

```
validates :time_zone, inclusion: { in: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys }
```

Where `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys` is an array of timezone names, which *does* respond to the `include?` method

Answer (score 2):

zones_map is a function and it already does the mapping

```
validates :time_zone, inclusion: { in: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map{ |el| el.last.name }, allow_nil: true }
```

Replace zones_map.map with zones_map

Comment: If I do that, I get a different error:
/Users/aljazfajmut/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/rails-c40bfc6eb2ba/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/clusivity.rb:11:in `check_validity!': An object with the method #include? or a proc, lambda or symbol is required, and must be supplied as the :in (or :within) option of the configuration hash (ArgumentError)

Comment: nvm, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950540/validates-inclusion-of-no-longer-working-the-same-in-rails-4-1#comment36837662_22950776 helped