# validates_inclusion_of no longer working the same in Rails 4.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport, ruby-on-rails-4.1

The following code made sure that a `time_zone` chose is within the time zones in `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones`:

```
validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, in: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map(&:name)
```

Worked great in Rails 4.0. Just upgraded to Rails 4.1 and I'm getting this error on my index  page (so just simply viewing the models):

> An object with the method #include? or a proc, lambda or symbol is
>   required, and must be supplied as the :in (or :within) option of the
>   configuration hash

I'm guessing from that, `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map(&:name)` is no longer a valid value for the `in` property?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try adding `.keys` ?

```
validates :time_zone, 
  inclusion: { 
    in: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys 
  }
```

Comment: Makes sense, I think it worked... I get a lot of other errors now too :(. Looks like I'm going to wait on rails 4.1...

Comment: The block argument, `&:name` is irrelevant with the 4.1 implementation. zones_map returns a ThreadSafe::Cache object, which isn't quite a hash.  It doesn't support the #include? method as a way to determine if the key is present.


`ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys` is sufficient in 4.1.

Answer (score 2):

In **Rails 5**, `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map` is a private method. Therefore, if you want your validation to work, I suggest the following syntax:

```
validates :time_zone, inclusion: { in: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name) }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using `validates_inclusion_of` this works as well:

```
validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, 
   :in => ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map(&:name).keys, 
   :message => "is not a valid time zone"
```