# Time zone validation in Rails 4: Time zone is not included in the list

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get the time zone validation in my form to pass, but every time I get the error message:

> Time zone is not included in the list.

I have this in my model:

```
validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, in: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys
```

And have this in my form:

```
<%= f.label :time_zone %>
<%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones  %>
```

I can't seem to find any solution that would help, I also tried this:

```
validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, :in => ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map(&:to_s)
```

as suggested previously on this site, and the validation doesn't pass either.

Any input would be great--thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, in: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map(&:name)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either :( apparently the &:name argument is no longer needed in Rails 4.1?

Comment: Review the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950540/validates-inclusion-of-no-longer-working-the-same-in-rails-4-1
may be it will be helpful for you